# What does the Filter::Crypto module do to the DATA section?

Tags: perl, cryptography

I'm trying to package a Perl script to EXE using the pp utility bundled with [PAR::Packer](http://search.cpan.org/dist/PAR-Packer/) with the [Filter::Crypto](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Filter-Crypto/) on. But something is wrong there. Without the filter, things are ok. With it, no. I think it has something to do with the DATA section in the script. The following simplified script might demonstrate the problem but I'm not sure if my problem is OS specific or not. The problem is this: when I use

```
pp --gui -o 1.exe test.pl
```

the EXE works like expected. It displays the content in the DATA section. But with

```
pp --gui -f Crypto -M Filter::Crypto::Decrypt -o 2.exe test.pl
```

the EXE does not output any content.

```
use Win32::GUI;
use strict;
use warnings;

my $mw = new Win32::GUI::DialogBox(
  -text         => 'Test',
  -left         => 300,
  -top          => 100,
  -left         => 60,
  -width        => 200,
  -height       => 200,
);

$mw->Show();

my $result = $mw->AddTextfield(
  -left         => 0,
  -top          => 40,
  -size         => [180,100],
  -vscroll =>1,
  -multiline => 1,
);

my $button = $mw->AddButton(
  -name         => 'button',
  -text         => 'Go',
  -left         => 120,
  -top          => 10,
  -visible =>1,
);

Win32::GUI::Dialog;

sub button_Click {

while(<DATA>) {
    $result->Append("$_\r\n");
}
}

__DATA__
This is LINE1
This is LINE2
This is LINE3
```

Thanks like always for any guidance/pointers/suggestions/comments :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have [reported this as a bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Display.html?id=54370) in [Filter::Crypto bug tracker](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Create.html?Queue=Filter-Crypto).